# How to design an efficient adversary for sorting?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, comparison

We know information theoretically number of comparisons for a comparison-based sorting algorithm is ceil(lg(n!)) where lg stands for logarithm to base 2.

We can build an adversary where we choose the ordering by counting number of linear extensions for the partial order in both cases if lessthan or if greaterthan. Whichever has higher linear extensions choose that path. (This automatically takes care of inconsistencies because if reply is inconsistent on one side it will be zero, and other will be same as the previous)

However such an adversary is not efficient as counting number of [linear extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) to a partial order is [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete).

Another option is to use a simpler polynomial time adversary which does:

1. a > b if a has never lost, and b has lost at least once.
2. a > b if both undefeated, and a has more wins than b.
3. a > b if the partial order forces a > b
4. a < b if the partial order forces a < b
5. choose any otherwise.

This adversary is taken from The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3, Second edition, page 209. Which works well for problems like find the second largest element as it forces n + ceil(lg(n)) - 2 comparisons. Unfortunately it doesn't force information theoretic bound for sorting. This remains true even if I add more heuristics like dominating count (number of values it is greater than) to compare instead of randomly choosing the order.

I know it doesn't force because Collections.sort() in Java 8, sorts a 23 element array in 74 comparisons, when the lowerbound is 75. The [source code](https://gist.github.com/anitasv/5210b38b5bd12f01a2b272d12c6adaaa) shows for all numbers less than 23 it was able force the lower bound, for 100 numbers sort() managed to do in506 comparisons when lower bound is 525.

Is there is a polynomial time efficient adversary which forces sorting algorithms to use at least information theoretic bound?

Answer (score 0):

There's a "probably approximately successful" polynomial time adversary that uses randomization to (for example) force ceil(lg(n!) − n<sup>−100</sup>) comparisons with probability at least 1 − n<sup>−100</sup>.

The key idea is that, while counting the number of linear extensions is hard, sampling uniform random extensions is easy (well, polynomial-time at least), hence we can get a probably approximately correct estimate of the number of extensions with a < b versus a > b. Obviously we can't tell which is more probable if the counts are close enough, but by taking enough samples (but still a polynomial number), we can provably ensure using a Hoeffding bound that, with probability at least 1 − n<sup>−102</sup>, the outcome that the adversary chooses is consistent with at least a 1/2 − n<sup>−102</sup> fraction of the linear extensions. We can bound the cumulative effects of these screw-ups by n<sup>−100</sup>.